# Character counter in C

Tags: c, syntax

This code with C language is supposed to count all characters equal to A in a table ..but it doesn't work I need help to find the Problem !! ~~
I've started by reading the table's characters giving by the user using a for loop and then i've used another for loop to count the number of characters equal to A~~

ANY suggestions please

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char T[100],A;
    int i,N,b=0;
    
    printf("give the number of your table's columns \n");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    if (N > 0 && N <= 100) {
        for (i; i < N; i++) {
            scanf("%c", &T[i]);

            printf("give the character of the column number %d \n", i);
            scanf("%c",&T[i]);
        }
     
        for (i; i < N; i++) {
            if (T[i] = 'A') b++; 

            printf("the number of characters equal to A is %d",b);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Format your code properly. Add indentation and remove extra blank lines. 2. Initialize `i` before using that. 3. `if(T[i]='A') b++;` doing assignment here looks weird.

Comment: you have to explicit better why it doesnt work: what error message etc? On top of MikeCAT comment you have to look at `if (N > 0 && N <= 100) ` :  you will have some problem because you try to write in your array at index 100 but your array ends at index 99 (size - 1). You should compile with **`gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra`** Also "printf("the number of characters equal to..." should be out of your loop (after } )

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL `if (N > 0 && N <= 100)` won't be trouble because there are conditions `i < N` before accessing the array `T[i]`.

Comment: Another problem is that your program may not behave as expected if your input consists of multiple lines.

Comment: @MikeCAT indeed

Comment: Ah, using `scanf("%c",&T[i]);` twice is eliminating problem with multiple-line input.

Comment: @MikeCAT, but using scanf twice like this is a terrible way to consume the unwanted newline!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be explicit in explaining  why it doesnt work: what error message, how do you compile, Do you need number 100 etc?

<s>On top of MikeCAT comment you have to look at if (N > 0 && N <= 100) : you will have some problem because you try to write in your array at index 100 but your array ends at index 99 (size - 1).</s>

You probably don't need to scanf twice, so you can remove the first one: `scanf("%c",&T[i])`

You should compile with `gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra`

Also `printf("the number of characters equal to...")` should be out of your loop (after `}` )

Your `return 0;` should also be out of your if condition and before the final `}`

Let me know if its helpful and start by amending your code.

Comment: if I won't write scanf("%c",&T[i]) twice ,with what should I replace it ? becuase when writing it one time it does another thing unwanted actually i couldn't understand the reason why

Comment: you might want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer

Answer (score 1):

> *"supposed to count all characters equal to A in a table ..but it doesn't work I need help to find the Problem !!"*

Compiler warnings will help you to find the problem.
If you are not seeing warnings when you compile, set your compiler to show them. ([in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) for example use `-Wall`)

*When compiling with warnings turned on* you should see information similar to this upon a compile:

```
Build Status (so.prj - Debug)
 s0_15.c - 3 warnings
  22, 22    warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses 
  22, 22    note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
  22, 22    note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
  7, 17     warning: unused variable 'A' 
  14, 14    warning: variable 'i' is uninitialized when used here 
  8, 10     note: initialize the variable 'i' to silence this warning
```

Additionally, when dropping down into the second `for()` loop, `i` again is not initialized, but left with the value it had when finishing the first loop.  It needs to be re-initialized to zero for that second loop to work...  (Note, my compiler *did not flag this*, fortunately I was told at one point to [learn how to set and use breakpoints](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_27.html) which I did here, allowing me to discover the value of `i` during runtime.

By following the guidance offered by the warnings above, modifications were made to allow the code to run, and does what you describe it should.

See comments in-line for the response to the warnings above:

```
int main(void)//added void to match accepted prototype of main
{
    char T[100] = {0},A;//A is not used, should be deleted
                        //initialize array to all zeros.
    int i=0,N=0,b=0;//initialized i (and N)
    
    printf("give the number of your table's columns \n");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    if (N > 0 && N <= 100) {
        for (i; i < N; i++) {
            scanf("%c", &T[i]);

            printf("give the character of the column number %d \n", i);
            scanf("%c",&T[i]);
        }
        // `i` is already equal to N here.  it will never enter the loop
        //for (i; i < N; i++) {         
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {//initialized i to zero
          //if (T[i] = 'A') b++;//this is not what you want
            if (T[i] == 'A') b++; //replace assignment '=' 
                                  //with    comparison '==' operator
            //Note, optionally move the following printf() statement to below 
            //the loop so it is called only once after counting is done.
            printf("the number of characters equal to A is %d\n",b);//added '\n' for readability of output.
        }
        //return 0;// not here...
    }
    return 0;// ...but here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C has a language feature (or flaw).  You can use the assignment operator in contexts where it is typically not wanted.

```
 if (T[i] = 'A') b++;
```

is changing `T[i]` and not comparting it to `A`.  This means the `if` statement is registering if the change was to a value that isn't `0`.

Use `==` and you'll be comparing again.

Comment: ...and it would be a very good idea to use `-Wall` with gcc, because then it actually warns about that.

Comment: @ilkkachu An excellent recommendation; and, ryyker has it covered already